# How to use Video files in java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Im trying to put video files into my maze game that i am working on. I am trying to put the video file right before the game starts so that it seems like an intro scene. I have looked everywhere and could not find anything. If you know then please tell. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can look at

- [Playing a media file in a Jframe java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733199/playing-a-media-file-in-a-jframe-java)
- [Show video to JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457269/show-video-to-jpanel)
- https://forums.oracle.com/message/5412780

They may help you out.

I'm assuming you're using a JFrame here.